# Android - Possible approach on creating custom shape buttons?

Tags: android, button, imageview

i would like to know how i will be able to create a set of buttons as shown in the image below.

[image: Figure 1]

i understand that imageviews can only be rectangular or square but in my case, these will be a set of custom shaped buttons that might overlap imageviews as shown in the image below.

[image: Figure 2]

in this image, i basically have 9 imageviews that should contain their respective images but notice that some of the image shown per imageview includes a part of an image from another imageview.

i plan to have the on press effect which i've done before using selector like the ff:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_1_down"/>
        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_1_down"/>
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_1_up"/>
        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_1_up"/>
    </selector>
```

but that only works for the current view as far as i know and it wont change images on the other imageviews affected. so in this case for example,

button 1 (top left). this buttons image is connected partly to imageview 2 and imageview 4. so when pressed lets say the button turns white, i would also like to the button's part in imageview 2 and 4 to turn white. how is this done?

appreciate any comment or suggestion.

Comment: I think that your question is off-topic on stackoverflow. We don't answer "tell me how to do" questions. Take a look at [the community guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see how to refine your question and get more chances to have an answer.

Comment: You're better off drawing your own view that creates these videos, not an easy feat :) Google actually did something like this for the Nexsus 5.. looks really cool, gonna have to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

check out this: https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android. this guy developed a pretty good radial menu like yours.